# Put all Msysgit's right-click context menu options in a sub-menu in Windows Exporer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, context-menu, msysgit

edit: [opened an issue on Git-Cheetah's GitHub page.](https://github.com/msysgit/Git-Cheetah/issues/20)

Is it possible to put all Msysgit's right-click menu options in a ***sub-***menu?

All of the options makes my menu enormous

[image]

Comment: I think you can do it with [File Menu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/filemenutools)